# Merging two SortedMapWritable in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hashmap

I have defined a class called `EquivalenceClsAggValue` which has a data field of array (called `aggValues`).

```
class public class EquivalenceClsAggValue extends Configured implements WritableComparable<EquivalenceClsAggValue>{

public ArrayList<SortedMapWritable> aggValues;
```

It has a method which take another object of type `EquivalenceClsAggValue` and merge its `aggValues` into `aggValues` of this class as follows:

```
public void addEquivalenceCls(EquivalenceClsAggValue eq){
    //comment: eq contains only one entry as it comes from the mapper

    if (this.aggValues.size()==0){ //new line
        this.aggValues = eq.aggValues;  
                    return;     
    }

    for(int i=0;i<eq.aggValues.size();i++){

        SortedMapWritable cm = aggValues.get(i); //cm: current map
        SortedMapWritable nm = eq.aggValues.get(i); //nm: new map
        Text nk = (Text) nm.firstKey();//nk: new key

        if(cm.containsKey(nk)){//increment the value
            IntWritable ovTmp = (IntWritable) cm.get(nk);
            int ov = ovTmp.get();
            cm.remove(nk);
            cm.put(nk, new IntWritable(ov+1));
        }
        else{//add new entry
            cm.put(nk, new IntWritable(1));
        }


    }
}
```

But this function is not merging two `aggValues`. Could someone help me figure it out?
This is how I call this method:

```
public void reduce(IntWritable keyin,Iterator<EquivalenceClsAggValue> valuein,OutputCollector<IntWritable, EquivalenceClsAggValue> output,Reporter arg3) throws IOException {

        EquivalenceClsAggValue comOutput = valuein.next();//initialize the output with the first input

        while(valuein.hasNext()){
            EquivalenceClsAggValue e = valuein.next();
            comOutput.addEquivalenceCls(e);             
        }           
        output.collect(keyin, comOutput);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the context of how you're calling this method - i suspect you're still falling foul of object reuse (trying to merge the object with itself).

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I added the way I call this function.

Comment: Did you override `hashCode` and `compareTo` in your custom `WritableComparable`?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy: No I haven't, and I don't know how to implement them. Could you guide me through that? (btw, as this Writable class in used as the output value, not key, is it necessary to implement those two functions?

Comment: You don't need hashCode or compareTo for values

Comment: It reuses the objects, that is `e` and `comOutput` are the same objects. Is there any way to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're falling foul of object re-use. Hadoop re-uses the same object so each call to `valuein.next()` actually returns the same object reference, but the contents of that object are re-initialised via the readFields method.

Try changing as follows (create a new instance to aggregate into):

```
 EquivalenceClsAggValue comOutput = new EquivalenceClsAggValue();

 while(valuein.hasNext()){
   EquivalenceClsAggValue e = valuein.next();
   comOutput.addEquivalenceCls(e);             
 }           
 output.collect(keyin, comOutput);
```

**EDIT**: and you probably need to update your aggregate method too (to be wary of object re-use):

```
public void addEquivalenceCls(EquivalenceClsAggValue eq){
  //comment: eq contains only one entry as it comes from the mapper

  for(int i=0;i<eq.aggValues.size();i++){

    SortedMapWritable cm = aggValues.get(i); //cm: current map
    SortedMapWritable nm = eq.aggValues.get(i); //nm: new map
    Text nk = (Text) nm.firstKey();//nk: new key

    if(cm.containsKey(nk)){//increment the value
        // you don't need to remove and re-add, just update the IntWritable
        IntWritable ovTmp = (IntWritable) cm.get(nk);
        ovTmp.set(ovTmp.get() + 1);
    }
    else{//add new entry
        // be sure to create a copy of nk when you add in to the map
        cm.put(new Text(nk), new IntWritable(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Spotted another problem in your aggregate method, see the edits

Comment: Assume that the valuein (input of the combiner) has only two items. In this case, the comOutput contains the values of the second item only increased by 1!

Comment: Do the objects always have aggValue lists of the same size? And you want to merge the two sorted maps (adding the elements with the same key together?)

Comment: I tried your new edits, it didn't work either. 
Exactly, objects have the same size and I'm trying to merge two sorted maps.
I code (in method addEquivalenceCls) has an extra condition which I added in my original post (marked as "new line"). This is for adding the first object to aggValues.

Comment: The main problem is cm.containsKey returns true, while it shouldn't.

Comment: you're right. It re-uses the objects. That is, `e` and `comOutput` are the same objects. I wonder to know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you able to share your full code for `EquivalenceClsAggValue` and some more info on how this is built up / output from the mapper?